# 2 of same model iPad - yet each shows totally different view of my site. Can anyone explain?

Tags: ios, css, ipad

Our small ecommerce site is 99% ready to launch with one remaining issue which is annoying and highly frustrating. NB: I'm not a developer so I don't understand coding.

**Problem: when viewing the site on two of the same model iPads, it is displaying differently on each one.**

Image link to illustrate - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nILeP.jpg

The top half of the image shows the homepage when viewed on my wife's iPad Mini (first gen).

The lower half of the image shows the homepage when viewed on my mother's iPad Mini (first gen).

As you can see, there are numerous differences in the second image:

- the top bar and social media icons aren't showing
- the top of the logo is chopped off
- a hamburger menu is present at right of the header
- a large gap exists above the image slider (which can't be seen in the image)

The only difference between the two iPads is that my wife's Mini was updated to iOS9 a couple of days ago.  I've asked my Mum (on other side of world) to update hers to iOS9 and obviously the resulting view after she updates will be relevant

**Has anyone here ever seen anything like this, or can help explain it?**

The url is sicilybag.com if anyone wants to take a look and let me know what they see on their iPads!  Would be great to see a few screengrabs with notation of which iPad model and iOS version.

Cheers,

Brad

Comment: Your media queries seems very sensible. If you test your two devices in a test like http://mqtest.io/, are there any differences?